# Unable to get jsessionid in cookies for first 2 attempts in mule 4

Tags: http-headers, mule, mulesoft, mule4, mule-esb

I am calling external rest services from mule using HTTP outbound component. When i call service 1st 2 times   JSESSIONID in Set-Cookie not present  but in 3rd  call JSESSIONID is present in Set-Cookie.
(when i call external service directly  in every call  getting jsessionid in set cookie ).

Is anyone faced the same ?

Comment: Did you check the HTTP debug logs and see if you are receiving the expected cookies from the external REST service?

Comment: Please share HTTP config and request and version used of Mule runtime and HTTP connector.

Comment: And what do you mean by "calling external service directly"?